# MongoDB indexing large text field doesn't seem to make query faster?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have 1.5 million records, each with a text field "body" that contains a lot of text.  I'm performing a full-text search against these documents using a regular expression but haven't noticed any difference in query times between indexing the data and not indexing it.

I ensured there was an index on the "body" field via

`db.documents.ensureIndex({ body: 1 });`

MongoDB took a few moments to index the data, and when I ran

`db.documents.getIndexes()`

it showed that I had an index on the collection's "body" field.  But queries still take the same amount of time before and after indexing.

If I run the query

`db.documents.find({ body: /test/i });`

I would expect it to run faster because the data is indexed.  When I do

`db.documents.find({ body: /test/i }).explain();`

mongo tells me that it's using the BTreeCursor on the body field.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Why would there not be any decrease in query time after the text data has been indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs for indexes and regex queries:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

> For simple prefix queries (also called rooted regexps) like /^prefix/,
>   the database will use an index when available and appropriate (much
>   like most SQL databases that use indexes for a LIKE 'prefix%'
>   expression). This only works if you don't have i (case-insensitivity)
>   in the flags.

Comment: It looks like I'm doing everything properly; it seems my query choice just isn't really engineered for MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Full text search is a dedicated area where MongoDb doesn't really fit.

If you're looking for something open source & fast, you should try Apache SOLR. We've been using it for 4 years now, a great value!

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TEXT search index on the field.

```
 db.documents.ensureIndex({ body: "text" });
```

once the TEXT search index is created, you can search as below :

```
 db.documents.find({ "$text": {"$search" : /test/i} });
```